# Images in /media/catalog/product/cache are created as root:root and hence give 403 errors?

Tags: media, product-images, apache

Images in `/media/catalog/product/cache` are created as `root:root`.

These images give 403 errors.

What file creates these cache files, is it Mage.php?

I have checked the root directory and all the files are `root:root` except `/media`.

I am hosting with `apache`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your apache isn't running as root (I'm assuming when you refer to a 403 you mean apache can't serve it), it's likely one of:

1. You have the cron running as root and one of the crons performs an action that causes image cache to get generated.
2. You ran a shell script from the CLI that performs an action that causes image cache to get generated.

Comment: Yes, `apache` is running as `www-data`

Comment: There are no cronjobs though...

Comment: If you delete the contents of `/media/catalog/product/cache` and make a request to the website, presumably the generated files will be owned by `www-data`, since apache shouldn't be able to chown them to root. Therefore the root ownership must be done outside of apache.

Comment: Oh there are `magento cronjobs`

Comment: The solution was to make sure magento is owned by `www-data`